# correct module organization with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I've built a small chess game in plain JavaScript, and in order to handle imports I just pushed them all into the html file, giving me the following:

**game.html**

```
.
.
<body id="body">
    <script src="scripts/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pieces.js"></script>
    .
    .
    .
    <script src="scripts/game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am starting to use Node.js and want to move the logic server-side and structure it properly using imports, but there are two files I'm having trouble with. The first one is

**utils.js**

```
function getEnemy(player) {
    return player===WHITE? BLACK : WHITE;
}

/**
 * A generator to generate pieces from given fen and return them all in an array.
 */
function generatePieces(fen) {

    var piece_array = [];
    var ranks = fen.split(' ')[0].split('/');
    for (var i=0; i < ranks.length; i++) {

        var squares = ranks[i];
        var rank = 8 - i;
        var file = 1; // keeping track of the current file.
        for (var j=0; j < squares.length; j++) {
            if (Number(squares[j])) {
                file += Number(squares[j]);
                continue;
            }
            var color = (squares[j] === squares[j].toUpperCase()? WHITE : BLACK);
            piece_array.push( generatePiece(squares[j], color, file, rank));
            file +=1;
        }
    }
    return piece_array;
}
function generatePiece(type, color, file, rank) {

    var square = new Square(file, rank);
    type = type.toUpperCase();
    switch(type) {
        case PAWN:
            return new Pawn(square, color);
        case KNIGHT:
            return new Knight(square, color);
        case KING:
            return new King(square, color);
        case BISHOP:
            return new Bishop(square, color);
        case ROOK:
            return new Rook(square, color);
        case QUEEN:
            return new Queen(square, color);
    }
}

/**
 * generates a square from the first two numbers in an array.
 * no validations are made.
 * @param position_array an array whose first two elements are numbers.
 * @returns {Square} a square with file equal to the first element and rank the second.
 */
function getSquareFromArray(position_array) {
    return new Square(position_array[0], position_array[1]);
}

/******* Square class
 * square object to encapsulate all these ugly arrays.
 * @param file file of the new square.
 * @param rank rank of the new square.
 */
function Square(file, rank) {
    this.file = file;
    this.rank = rank;

    /**
     * Checks if two squares have the same file and rank.
     * @param other another square
     * @returns {boolean} true if both squares are of the same position on the board.
     */
    this.equals = function(other) {
       return (this.file === other.file && this.rank === other.rank);
    };

    /**
     * Returns a string version of the square, formatted as "file rank".
     * @returns {string} string version of the square.
     */
    this.toString = function() {
        return String(file) + ' ' + String(rank);
    };


    /**
     * returns a new square with the given file and rank added to this square's file and rank.
     * @param file file to move the square
     * @param rank rank to move the square
     * @returns {Square}
     */
    this.getSquareAtOffset = function(file, rank) {
        file = Number(file)? file : 0;
        rank = Number(rank)? rank : 0;
        return new Square(this.file + file, this.rank + rank);
    };
}

/**
 * creates a new square object from a string of format '%d $d'
 * @param string string in format '%d %d'
 * returns square object
 */
function getSquareFromKey(string) {
    values = string.split(' ');
    return new Square(Number(values[0]), Number(values[1]));
}
/******* Move object
 * Move object to encapsulate a single game move.
 * Might be a bit of an overkill, but I prefer an array of moves over an array of arrays of squares.
 * @param from A square to move from.
 * @param to A square to move to.
 */
function Move(from, to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

/******* SpecialMove object
 * Move object to encapsulate a single game move.
 * Might be a bit of an overkill, but I prefer an array of moves over an array of arrays of squares.
 * @param moves array of moves to make
 * @param removes array of squares to remove pieces from
 * @param insertions array of triplets, square to insert, wanted piece type, and piece color.
 */
function SpecialMove(moves, removes, insertions) {
    this.moves = moves? moves : [];
    this.removes = removes? removes : [];
    this.insertions = insertions? insertions : [];
}
```

Which I'm not sure how to properly export. If I add each function/object individually to module.exports then for each of my objects using this module (which is pretty much any other object) I'll need to do something like `this.utils = require('./utils');` and then call, for example, `square = new this.utils.Square(file, rank);`, which doesn't seem like all that good of a solution. Is there a nicer way of importing this file pretty much globally?

The second is a list of objects for the different types of pieces
 **pieces.js**

```
var WHITE = 'w';
var BLACK = 'b';

var PAWN = 'P';
var KNIGHT = 'N';
var KING = 'K';
var BISHOP = 'B';
var ROOK = 'R';
var QUEEN = 'Q';

/********* Piece class
 * The parent class of all piece types.
 * @param square square of the piece.
 * @param color color of the piece, should be either 'white' or 'black'.
 * @constructor
 */
function Piece(square, color) {
    this.square = square;
    this.color = color;
}

/**
 * Returns the path the piece needs in order to get to the given square, if it's not a capture.
 * Returns null if the piece can't reach the square in one move.
 * @param to target square.
 */

Piece.prototype.getPath = function(to) {
    return null;
};

/**
 * Returns the path the piece needs in order to capture in the given square.
 * Returns null if the piece can't reach the square in one move.
 * Implement this if the piece captures in a different way then moving (i.e. a pawn);
 * @param to target square.
 */

Piece.prototype.getCapturePath = function(to) {
    return this.getPath(to);
};

/**
 * Compares the square of the piece with given square
 * @returns {boolean} if the piece is at the given square.
 */

Piece.prototype.isAt= function(square) {
  return (this.square.equals(square));
};

/******* Pawn class
 * Holds the movement of the pawn, refer to Piece for explanations.
 * @type {Piece}
 */
Pawn.prototype = Object.create(Piece.prototype);
Pawn.prototype.constructor = Pawn;
function Pawn(square, color) {
    Piece.call(this, square, color);
    this.startPosition = (color === WHITE? 2 : 7);
    this.direction = (color === WHITE? 1 : -1);

    this.type = PAWN;
}

.
.
.

/******* Knight class
 * Holds the movement of the Knight, refer to Piece for explanations.
 * @type {Piece}
 */
Knight.prototype = Object.create(Piece.prototype);
Knight.prototype.constructor = Knight;
function Knight(square, color) {
    Piece.call(this, square, color);

    this.type = KNIGHT;
} 
.
.
.
/******* King class
 * Holds the movement of the King, refer to Piece for explanations.
 * @type {Piece}
 */
King.prototype = Object.create(Piece.prototype);
King.prototype.constructor = King;
function King(square, color, has_moved) {
    Piece.call(this, square, color);

    this.type = KING;
}
.
.
.
```

Where I'm not sure how to correctly import all different "classes" for use in other places. I thought making the `generatePiece` function from `util.js` the `module.export` of this file, thus turning it into a sort of "piece generator". is that a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a defacto way of doing things in node.js, I'll try in give a couple generalized solutions:

> I thought making the generatePiece function from util.js the
>   module.export of this file, thus turning it into a sort of "piece
>   generator". is that a good idea?

I think that using your modules as standalone utils is a very straightforward and elegant solution. It is easily unittestable and is constantly used in node.js projects.

> . If I add each function/object individually to module.exports then
>   for each of my objects using this module (which is pretty much any
>   other object) I'll need to do something like this.utils =
>   require('./utils'); and then call, for example, square = new
>   this.utils.Square(file, rank);, which doesn't seem like all that good
>   of a solution. Is there a nicer way of importing this file pretty much
>   globally?

Instead of storing a `require`d library as a property in your object you could just construct new squares through the global reference, which is commonly used:

`utils = require('./utils'); and then call, for example,`square = new utils.Square(file, rank);`

Or even subdivide your modules even further, maybe even create a pieces module, or a board module.

I try to create as many modules as make sense.  One benefit is that there are lots of libraries in node to mock along `require`s.  If you end up doing IO it could be important to mock that for your unittests.